# Is there an automatic way to generate a spec file skeleton in Galen Framework

Tags: html, layout, cross-browser, galen, visual-testing

I want to perform a visual and layout testing on a UI which is being migrated to HTML-5. What I discovered is Galen Framework suffices all my need from a validation perspective.

But since this is a legacy application transformed to new UI with a huge number of complex components present on each screen, generating a spec file is a challenge. Identifying and tracking hundreds of elements in the spec file manually is a tedious task.

Want to know, if someone has already experienced such an issue and how was it overcome. Is there an automatic way used to generate a spec file for the specified screen with multifarious elements?

Comment: If you want to do visual testing without writing specs, have a look at tools that follow the [golden master principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test). Such tools often use image comparison (e.g. [Depicted](https://github.com/bslatkin/dpxdt)), but you may also like [recheck-web](https://github.com/retest/recheck-web) (disclaimer: I'm a contributor).

Comment: Thanks @beatngu13, will explore the technique you mentioned.